# Asp MVC IIS User permission

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis

I use this code in my application to display some images stored on a network drive, for example with the path //MyCompanyServer/Folder

```
public ActionResult DocumentoLista(string area)
{
    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(area))            
    {
        return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
    }

    var doc = db.Documentos.Where(x => x.area == area).FirstOrDefault();

    if (doc == null)
    {
        return HttpNotFound();
    }
    string dirPath = Path.GetFullPath(doc.path);

    List<string> dirs = new List<string>(Directory.EnumerateDirectories(dirPath));

    List<string> files = new List<string>();
    DirectoryInfo dirInfo = new DirectoryInfo(dirPath);
    foreach (string fInfo in Directory.EnumerateFiles(dirPath, "*.*", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly)
                    .Where(s => s.EndsWith(".png")
                        || s.EndsWith(".PNG")
                        || s.EndsWith(".jpg")  
                        || s.EndsWith(".JPG")
                     ).Select(Path.GetFileName)
             )
    {
        files.Add(fInfo);
    }
    ViewBag.Area = area;
    ViewBag.Dirs = dirs;
    ViewBag.MyList = files;
    return View(doc);
}
```

It works perfectly on my dev machine but when I tried it from my deployment server, it doesn´t work. I think that maybe it´s not working because in my dev computer I´m executing it with my LDAP user and in my production server (IIS) the user is different and it doesn´t have permision to access to this path.
¿Could be?

Witch user executes asp applications? to what user do I need to give permissions in order to make it work?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Pretty sure that the user your application pool is running under doesn't have permissions for that path, you need to:

1. Locate your application pool in IIS
2. Check the user account it's running against (In Basic Settings)
3. Give that user access to the path that you're trying to access (using windows security).

Answer (score 0):

Give `IUSR` access to the folder.

http://www.iis.net/learn/get-started/planning-for-security/understanding-built-in-user-and-group-accounts-in-iis